# Broadcast receiver push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-broadcast

I have implemented push notification in my android application:

In my main class:

```
// PUSH
Parse.initialize(this, applicationId, clientKey); 
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, SlidingMenuActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

In my manifest.xml:

```
<!-- PUSH -->
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When i open my application, i am receiving notification. I click on back and close the application.
I still receiving notification for approximatively 1 hours. After one hour, i send three notification and no notification appear. So i restart my app, and three notification notification appear.

I guess my broadcast receiver has been recreated. Why my android is killing my notification broadcast receiver?

How can i fix that?

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Are you using Push or custom broadcasts? They are different things. You should give some more details in your question.

Comment: It may be possible that you unregister your Broadcast Receiver in your onPause(). Do you?

Comment: how u achieve custom broadcast reciver work in your app @haythem souissi

Answer (score 0):

try my solution it worked for me:
link your broadcast receiver to your service by adding

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //add the following
    Intent e = new Intent(context, urservice.class);
    context.startService(e);
}
```

then register your receiver in your service onCreate() like so

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.BOOT_COMPLETED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.USER_PRESENT);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ParseBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

then just delete your 'broadcastreceiver' from the manifest, lastly surly you want the service to live as long as possible,,, well then you need also 2 codes for the service in your int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) make sure you put the following

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent bIntent = new Intent(urservice.this, urmain.class);       
    PendingIntent pbIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(urservice.this, 0 , bIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder bBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("sub title")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(pbIntent);
    barNotif = bBuilder.build();
    this.startForeground(1, barNotif);
// also the following code is important 
return Service.START_STICKY;
```

now make return sticky at the end of your onstartcommand. feel free to ask me.

hope I helped,,, good luck.   :)

Comment: anyway I'm glad I helped u haythem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your device going to sleep? Is it getting low on memory? All of these things you have to consider. You may have to hold a wake lock or start a service that returns a value to restart sticky.